# MS Access Date triggers emulation

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am completely new to Access (have some experience with SQL server).

I am not sure if its even possible in MS Access 2010:
if for one of table.dateField is today or earlier - need to send email about that record.

Extensive digging doesn't bring any results, seems its not feasible, but wanted group opinion on that.
Thank you

Comment: Access 2010 data macros have a [SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196780%28v=office.14%29.aspx) macro action. Have you tried that?

Comment: @GordThompson Tt doesnt match my requirement my requirement - SendEmail will only operate on action on certain record. I need even without any activity in the database to have a trigger that will notify that date is today and email have to be sent regardless... Thanks for the comment, unfortunately the obvious choice is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. So when you say "even without any activity in the database" do you mean that these emails need to be sent periodically (say, once per day) *even if there is nobody using the Access application* (i.e., the email process should be completely independent of any front-end code that users interact with)?

Comment: No, just in case one of records have a date of today, email shuold be sent saying this record is expired and provide some information what record it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are meaning that you need to execute say a query on a table, and that query will manage the execution of sending an email in respect of each offending row - then I dont think you'll have much luck;

You can open an email window from access, but this won't send an email by itself.

What are you using for your backend? If it's flexible, and you used SQL server for the backend then you could use an actual trigger which calls a stored procedure to send the email required.

Aside from this, all I can think of to do, would be

- create a query which finds the rows for which an email is to be sent;
- create a .net executable which receives a set of information as parameters & sends the email you require on the basis of that data,
- on a form in your application, use a timer event to periodically execute the logic to open the query, using like an adodb.recordset and loop through the recordset and call the .net executable for each row returned by the query.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave up the idea of having access as backend, now its MSSQL. Question - how to define a trigger that will trigger me once date in one of fields in the table is today or less? Thank you!

Comment: @DisplayName Note that the solution I offered in my answer would work just as well with a SQL Server database as it would with an Access database. All you would really need to do would be to change the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Access *application* does not have any built-in feature to automatically scan the database and send email messages based on the status of records in a table. However, that does not mean that such a function is "not feasible" for information stored in an Access database. In fact, implementing such a feature could be as simple as this:

The following VBScript code could be run (via `cscript.exe`) every morning as a Scheduled Task under Windows. It will scan a table named [Patients] and send a "Happy Birthday" message to each person who has a birthday that day.

```vbs
Option Explicit

Dim con  ' As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst  ' As ADODB.Recordset
Dim msg  ' As CDO.Message

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  ' New ADODB.Connection
con.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  ' New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open _
        "SELECT FirstName, Email " & _
        "FROM Patients " & _
        "WHERE Month(DOB) = Month(Date()) " & _
            "AND Day(DOB) = Day(Date())", _
        con
Do Until rst.EOF
    Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  ' New CDO.Message
    msg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    msg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.example.com"
    msg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    msg.Configuration.Fields.Update

    msg.To = rst("Email").Value
    msg.From = "admin@example.com"
    msg.Subject = "Happy Birthday!"
    msg.TextBody = "Hi, " & rst("FirstName").Value & ". We hope you have a great birthday today!"
    msg.Send

    Set msg = Nothing
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```