# Triggering an mdb query on server

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have a Microsoft Access MDB file on a website to which an ASP classic code adds rows.

How do I create a query/module that will run every time I add a row or automatically once a day?

Comment: For an example of a "once per day" type of operation on an Access database take a look at the VBScript in my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19594875/2144390). A script like that could be run as a Scheduled Task in Windows as often as needed (within practical limits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for something to run when a row is added, you're looking for "triggers" - which is not available in Access*. You find that sort of thing in proper RDBMSs like SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

If you're looking for something to run once a day, you could create a small VBS/PowerShell/etc. script and set up a scheduled task on the server to run it at an appropriate time.

You could also run the query in response to a page. If this is something that you want done after insert, then you can append the appropriate code to the end of the page or have it run as a part of the "success" page (if you have one).

---

* Unless you are using a `.accdb` (Access 2010 and later) file and the appropriate drivers. Then it appears you can use [Event-Driven Data Macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx#_Toc264895168) to get the same effect. Thank you [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665774/triggering-an-mdb-query-on-server/19665872?noredirect=1#comment29206944_19665872).

Comment: Correction: Access 2010 and later support [event-driven Data Macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx#_Toc264895168) in `.accdb` files that can fire any time there is an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on a table.

Comment: @Zephram Yes, it is possible to "run a query" from ASP code. (That's almost certainly how the ASP application adds rows to the database.)

Comment: I'll have to buy Access 2010 then. This is great news !

What command line do I use to fire a file on every line added?

Comment: @Zephram - there's almost always a way to do it programmatically with the right drivers. I'd investigate that before I spent the money.