# What I want related to database in Access about expiration date

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm creating database in Access.

This database has a table contain policy and procedure with expiration date for each one  for the company

each policy and procedure have expiration date

what i want when one of this policy or procedure expire it send me a notification to my email contain  the policy or procedure with the expiry date

The expiry date of course related with current date

could you please help me how i do it

Comment: You want the ms-access to constantly check this table and sends you an email when your condition is achieved?? I know that you can program in it using VBscript but I don not know if you will have this kind of operation on it, a job and email sender. I strongly recommend you to study any programming language to use your database and do this. Only from ms access i believe you can't

Comment: @jarlh this is not a query requirement. He wants to add a job on this access database. The query to trigger the email send process will be the least of his problem

Comment: @JorgeCampos, thanks for pointing the obvious out for me! It's finally Friday, and obviously I need to rest now... Have a nice weekend!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19594875/2144390

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: where should i type this code?? @GordThompson

Comment: You save the VBScript code as a .vbs file and then execute it using CSCRIPT.EXE. As mentioned in the answer, you can use the Task Scheduler in Windows to run it automatically every day.

Comment: thank you my dear @GordThompson