# When using Microsoft Access to collect data by using email messages, how do I change the from email address?

Tags: ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access to collect data by using email messages, as described here:
https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Collect-data-by-using-e-mail-messages-800DAEF3-86D3-4B62-9A2C-A4E41A14FA98

The from address in all of the emails sent by Access is my individual address, but I would like to send the emails from the team's group account.

Is there a way I can change the from address?

Comment: It's gonna send from your default Outlook address.  Either change the default Outlook address, or do it in code.  Gord has a nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572156/ms-access-date-triggers-emulation/19594875#19594875) that shows how to use VBA to send an email via CDO, and you can change the "From" address using it.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. The ideal solution would be where we can use the built in Access wizard data form sending and reply parsing mechanisms rather than write any new code, so we can use that for now.